# Possible to adjust "slide tolerance" on the Windows 10 tap gesture

Tags: windows, uwp, touch, gesture, tap

We've run into a tricky situation developing our Windows application (problem applies to both our old WinForm-based app as well as our new UWP-based app). The application is used on a touch screen based device  (15 – 27 inch touch screen depending on system size). Hence, no touch pad involved. Touch screen only (which does not have any Windows-related adjustments available that does effect this scenario. The touch device is identified as a “10-point multi touch screen” by Windows.

When using the tap-gesture (as opposed to previously using PointerPressed) the interface gets *very* picky about the way the user taps. If there is only the slightest "glide" when the finger touches the button (which is very often the case, it turns out, in usability studies) the pan-event is trigged (as opposed to the tap-event) and the button is not "pressed". The pan gesture is used for other purposes in the application.

The problem is specifically noticeable on smaller devices (with higher DPI). Probably a function of the finger used "does not scale" as the display does.
Is there a way to adjust for high DPI for the tap gesture? Something along the lines “if the slide is less than x pixels, then it’s not a pan but a tap”-kind of value?

“Google” has little to offer on the subject.. On the other hand - we simply cannot be the first to run into this situation!?

Comment: Try to see if anything in [SystemParametersInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow) can be used to change the behavior (like the double-click rectangle).

Comment: Very good suggestion. This particular struct does not seem to have any paramaters relating to gestures though (except one dealing with gesture visualization) but perhaps there is another, newer one dealing with gestures. Great input for a session with Google.. :) Thanks alot!

Comment: This was a no-go. Any (at all) other suggestions would be _very_ appreceiated. I doubt I'm the only one who has run into this situation!?